# Slide de conteúdo com HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de fazer um *slide* de conteúdo com *HTML* e *CSS*, o *slide* que preciso contém tudo abaixo do cabeçalho. Vou explicar melhor...

Normalmente se usa o menu para navegar pelas páginas, então ao clicar nesse link a página atual é redirecionada para outra, porém o que eu quero é ter botões na página principal e ao clicar neles ao invés de redirecionar o usuário para outra página, simplesmente rola o conteúdo da página atual e exibe o conteúdo da outra página. Em outras palavras seria como um slide de imagens, porém com todo o conteúdo da página exceto o cabeçalho.

Consegui um resultado parecido com o que desejo usando o seguinte código:

```css
.div {
  display: none;
  width: 0%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.div:target {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#conteudo1">Conteúdo 1</a>
<a href="#conteudo2">Conteúdo 2</a>

<div id="conteudo1" class="conteudo">Conteudo da primeira div</div>
<div id="conteudo2" class="conteudo">Conteudo da segunda div</div>
```

Porém dessa forma não consegui fazer a transição parecida com a de um slide, "empurrando" o conteúdo atual para a esquerda.

Gostaria de saber se eu posso utilizar este código dessa forma, ou tem alguma outra forma melhor de fazer isso.

Comment: Qual a função dessa classe `.div`? Aliás,  a pergunta está muito vaga. Coloque na pergunta também a estrutura do HTML/CSS que você já montou.

Comment: As divs ou section vão armazenar todo o conteúdo da página, por exemplo, a div 1 terá todos os posts, a div 2 terá o formulário de contato. ainda não montei nenhuma estrutura html, ainda estou fazendo os testes para que isso funcione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara esse layout não é muito complicado, mas tem que ficar atento em alguns detalhes.

Primeiro é que a vc precisa usar `overflow` em alguns elementos e valores com `VW` e `VH` para ocupar a largura e altura corretas na telas. O `scroll-behavior: smooth;` Vai dar o efeito de *transição* quando a "ancora" do *link* chamar o conteúdo. E o `position:fixed` deixa a `Nav` no lugar. Como esses valores relativos e flex ficou tudo até bem responsivo!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da forma como montei não precisa mudar nada no CSS basta ir incluindo as Sections e adicionando os links que vai fincionar direitinho ;)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
section {
  min-width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  transition: all 1s;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#conteudo1">Conteúdo 1</a>
    <a href="#conteudo2">Conteúdo 2</a>
    <a href="#conteudo3">Conteúdo 3</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <section id="conteudo1">
    <h1>conteudo 1</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="conteudo2">
    <h1>conteudo 2</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="conteudo3">
    <h1>conteudo 3</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```